# How to avoid adf pipeline converting the date fields to datetime while writing CSV files?

Tags: sql, datetime, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, apache-synapse

I have the source from Azure synapse, where i have below query as input

```
select ID, cast(created_date as date) as createddate
from table
```

In, sink I am writing the output data to a csv file

In the output I am getting the createddate as `03-05-2024 00:00:00.0000000` where as the expected date is only `03-05-2024`. Why ADF is adding the timestamp while provided input is just a date. How to fix this issue ?

I tried using format options but they are coming as string data type in the csv files like "03-05-2024" which is not again expected (expecting as date type without quotes), please help

Comment: In the rfc4180 compliant standard CSV format, a date is either an ISO date, `"2024-03-05"` or an American date, `"03/05/2024"` or a European date - mostly `"05.03.2024"` - formatted as string, so enclosed by the double quote - as you get it. Standard loaders will accept `"Harry's Bar"` as a string, and, for example `"2024-03-05"` as a date literal. Try loading the CSV file using a standard loader, or opening it with Excel (if it's not too huge), and you should be fine like that.

Comment: It detects the data type, and doesn't distinguish between date and datetime for this. You can get around by casting to varchar in the sql. And fwiw, most locales that use dash separators (instead of / slash ) in the date will treat that as dd-mm-yyyy instead of mm-dd-yyyy on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Joel Coehoorn cast created_date to varchar instead of date data type:

```
select ID, cast(created_date as varchar(20) ) as createddate from  <TableName>
```

You will get the data as required format in csv file as shown below:

[image]